# What is the optimal way to copy data between two identical objects

Tags: c#-3.0

Imagine I have two very complex but identical objects in c#, and I want to copy, say 3 arbitaty fields from the first object to the second object.

Is their an optimal way of copy X arbitary fields between one object and other. This is done all over the shop. What is the optimal way of doing it.

I'm not looking for any info about cloning interface or memberwise method. 
Thanks
Bob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take a look at [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper) which allows you to map different objects.

Comment: Hi Darin,
Cool. Does the mapping rules need to be defined before hand, i.e static definitions, or can they be dynamic. I need dynamic, as its my users, who write the mapping rules, through a custom rule definition.

Comment: Mappings are defined using a fluent API once per AppDomain and are usually defined in some static constructor. There's also a possibility for dynamic mappings (http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/04/14/automapper-feature-interfaces-and-dynamic-mapping.aspx).

Comment: Darin, had a look at it last night, its an excellent product, I could have used it 10 years ago, but I don't think you can create mappings on the fly, which is what I really need. Bob.

Comment: I ended up using a cloner to clone the object, fire it through a concurrentqueue, instead of having two comms over queue.